# Java sql read+write - prevent race condition?

Tags: java, mysql

I have two threads calling a method that performs a read and then a write of a record in a mysql database. Some pseudo code:

```
public void incrementRowValue() {
    Connection conn = ...;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        int value = conn.execute("select value from foo where id = 123");
        value += 1;
        conn.execute("update foo set value = " + value + " where id = 123");  

        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        conn.rollback(); 
    }
    finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

So if the threads execute about the same time, it looks like the read+write is not performed as one atomic item. For example, with a starting value of zero, my logs show that if both threads executed at about the same time, the ending value can be one instead of two.

Is there a different locking level I can use to prevent this? I can synchronize in java code if necessary of course, but I'm probably missing a big feature here that the database level provides for us.

Thanks

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to wrap the SQL into one statement and let the SQL server handle it, I can't remember the exact syntax off hand but it would be something like:

```
    conn.execute("update foo set value = (select value from foo where id = 123)+1 where id = 123");
```

The SQL server will lock the row being used (and if using multiple rows will lock them all) and perform the operation atomically.

This will also be faster/more efficient as it only makes the single database call instead of two. This sort of update could really do with being wrapped into a stored procedure though.

Comment: The code I'm actually trying to execute will make that unwieldy - is there any way to lock a specific row?

Comment: You need to use SQL transactions. If you set it up right and start a transaction and then access a row within the transaction then it will lock the row until the transaction ends. I'd still recommend doing the whole thing within one stored procedure though.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow - then shouldn't my trivial example work as-is then? It accesses only a single row within a transaction.

Comment: Yes but doing a read like that doesn't lock the row, you need to set the isolation level for the transaction because otherwise just reading from a row doesn't lock it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: I've checked connection.getTransactionIsolation() and it returns TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ for me. Looking at the doc, it looks like that level should prevent dirty reads. But it does not prevent phantom reads. Is that what I'm running into here?

Comment: Potentially. Honestly I've always controlled transactions from within a stored procedure and done it all in SQL so I'm not really able to give you any more than I have :)

Comment: Gotcha, ok I'm using the highest isolation level for these queries now, waiting to see if the problem comes up again. Based on the link to those issues, it sounds like this is what I was running into.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the lost update problem. You could use a Exclusive lock. This will prevent other transactions from reading the locked data.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can manage database concurrency using isolation levels

Isolation Level     Dirty Read  Nonrepeatable Read  Phantom Read
READ UNCOMMITTED    Permitted   Permitted   Permitted
READ COMMITTED  --  Permitted   Permitted
REPEATABLE READ     --  --  Permitted
SERIALIZABLE

SERIALIZABLE-it provide highest level of concurrency

For details please  refer :

[http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html][1]
```